# Publisher subscriber pattern communication between Angular 6 applications via iframe

Tags: angular, iframe, design-patterns

I'm working on a solution where an angular application is consumed inside an iframe of another angular application. The child app need some parameters to show the correct information into the app parent. I read a lot of solution around the web and a good solution is to apply the design pattern publisher/subscriber.

A lot of example are between component inside the same application and I'm wondering if the same solution with rxjs objects is the right way (as shown [here](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/25/angular-6-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject)).

My doubt is: how I subscribe the child application to the parent (an external publisher)?

I was thinking on a REST API exposed by the parent for registration and unregistration of subscriber, but I'm not sure.

Any experience with this situation? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I've seen this done, is via `CustomEvent` objects.

The page that wants to send a notification does it using this:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        /* The parent window hosts the Angular application */
        const parent = window.parent;
        /* Send an event to the message handler */
        const event = new CustomEvent('example-unique-string', { field1: 'value', field2: 'value' });
        parent.dispatchEvent(event);
    };
</script>
```

You then handle this message using:

```
window.addEventListener('example-unique-string', () => { /* some function */ }, false);
```

And of course, you can do it in both directions.

I would of course avoid using the `iframe` at all if I can, but you'll know what's appropriate for your situation.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply Cobus, but we need the iframes to include our app inside a portal that collects all the sub-apps for a client. The only solution we see is iframe. Do you see other solutions?

Comment: It's hard to say without having more info, but there are cases when we can't escape them. Another example is silent authentication token refresh scenarios. If the solution works for you, please remember to accept it.

Comment: I will try soon and come back to you

Answer (score 0):

you can make a use of window.postmessage method to post the messsage across iframe and parent application. You can also post the data along with the event.
https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication

You can refer to above link to post the message to and from iframe.